# How to use secure websockets (wss)?

Tags: apache, ssl, websocket, autobahn, thruway

I'm using AutobahnJS and Thruway on my website and everything works fine using a nonencrypted connection:

```
var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
                                             url: 'ws://www.example.com:9090',
                                             realm: 'restricted_realm'
                                         });

connection.onopen = function (session) {
    alert('yay');
};

connection.open();
```

However, I am unable to use a secure connection. Changing `ws://www.mysite.com:9090` to `wss://www.example.com:9090` results in this error in the console:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.example.com:9090/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

I have an SSL certificate on my server and can access my site via `https://www.example.com`.

What do I need to do to make secure websockets work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Thruway](https://github.com/voryx/Thruway) uses [Ratchet](http://socketo.me) as the underlying transport for WebSockets, so you can reference their documentation on deploying:

http://socketo.me/docs/deploy

You can also use stunnel or [nginx](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ratchet-php/dj-PgPPO_J0/k2hp7fvKdV8J).

Answer (score 1):

I use [HAProxy 1.5+](http://www.haproxy.org/) for [SSL termination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL_termination_proxy). Here is part of my config from production.

```
frontend public
    # HTTP
    bind :80
    # Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

    # HTTPS
    bind :443 ssl crt ssl.pem no-sslv3 ecdhe prime256v1 ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
    acl        is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
    use_backend    ws if is_websocket #is_websocket_server
    default_backend    www

backend ws
    server    ws1    127.0.0.1:9090

backend www
    timeout server  30s
    server  www1    127.0.0.1:8080
```

In my configuration, Apache listening for **unencrypted** traffic on port *8080* and WebSocket server listening **unencrypted** traffic on port *9090*